# rails two different layout templates in same controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a PagesController with a layout 'pages.html.erb' specified.

```
  class PagesController < Spree::StoreController
    layout 'pages'
    respond_to :html

    def lifestyle
      render 'lifestyle'
    end

    def co_step_1
      render 'co_step_1'
    end

    def co_step_2
      render 'co_step_2'
    end

  end
```

Is it possible to have an additional method in PagesController that uses a different layout?
In other words i want to override the `layout 'pages.html.erb'` in an additional method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A bit different answer from the others. No need for before actions or similar, just use a `layout` and method to distinguish which layout to use, like:

```
class PagesController < Spree::StoreController

    layout :resolve_layout
    respond_to :html

    def lifestyle
      render 'lifestyle'
    end

    def co_step_1
      render 'co_step_1'
    end

    def co_step_2
      render 'co_step_2'
    end

   private

   def resolve_layout
     action_name == 'pages' ? 'pages' : 'custom_layout'
   end

end
```

Or whatever logic you want to use to decide which layout to use.

Comment: This is better than a `before_action` hook.

Comment: It works fine. I used it in application controller for all pages. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can set the layout *per controller* if you want.

```
def some_special_method
  render layout: "special_layout"
end
```

Which is in the Rails guides which are super useful: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can specify the layout option

```
def my_new_layout
  render layout: "my_new_layout"
end
```

Comment: I have made this confusing though.  This would render `app/views/layouts/my_new_layout.html.erb` as the layout with `app/views/pages/my_new_layout` as the view file.

Answer (score 1):

You can also add a method that runs before each action to determine the layout, for example

```
 class PagesController < Spree::StoreController
    before_action :set_layout 
    respond_to :html

    def lifestyle
      render 'lifestyle'
    end

    def co_step_1
      render 'co_step_1'
    end

    def co_step_2
      render 'co_step_2'
    end

    private
    def set_layout
      %w(co_step_1 co_step_2).include?(params[:action]) ? "pages" : "other"
    end
  end
```

Comment: Shouldn't your `set_layout` method be `%w(co_step_1 co_step_2).include?(params[:action]) ? "pages" : "other"`

Comment: yup, I should answer questions until after coffee, thanks. :)

Comment: An affliction we all suffer with :)